# How to fix Error 508 in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice

I am super new to UBUNTU and have recently switched to Open Source from Windows.

I have a Microsoft spreadsheet that I have downloaded, and now in LibreOffice Calc, I am getting Error 508 in a few columns.

Is there any suggestion on how to fix this and how am I going to be able to work on this spreadsheet in UBUNTU 14.04?

Comment: Thanks, BUt this spreadsheet is working on Microsoft Excel. It is an original spreadsheet that i have downloaded from the original source. I mean there is no mistake in formulas.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [list of error codes](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Error_Codes_in_Calc), Error 508 means your brackets don't add up. Maybe you opened a bracket and didn't close it, or you closed more brackets than you have openend before.

Answer (score 4):

This error means your brackets don't add up.

See https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Error_Codes_in_Calc

=SUM(B3;B8;B5;B7) is OK

But =SUM(B3;B8;B5,B7) is NOT.

Although the brackets added up ok. but because of the formula evaluation ended upon the error separator ",",

it becomes =SUM(B3;B8;B5, that accounts for the missing ")".

This is one of those software nightmare or software jokes, depending on your mood.